# Entity Framework 5 complex type and unknown column in field list error

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Bear with me as I'm new to C# and programming in general.

I'm trying to define a complex type that is in the same table as the principle class.  Basically, it's the good old User and Address example.

```
public class Customer
{
    [Key]
    public int customerId { get; set; }

    //some attributes

    public string street { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string province { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
    public string postal { get; set; }
}
```

So I try to slice off the address information into its own class:

```
public class Customer
{
    [Key]
    public int customerId { get; set; }

    //some attributes
    public Address address { get; set; }
}

[ComplexType]
public class Address
{
    public string street { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string province { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
    public string postal { get; set; }
}
```

I get no compile error and when I load a view that access the Customer model, I get an unknown column in field set error.

> Unknown column 'Extent1.address_street' in 'field list'

I basically followed this example: http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/11/entity-association-mapping-with-code-first-part-1-one-to-one-associations.aspx

Is there something I"m missing or something different with EF5?

Comment: BTW, the first code block does work and it's currently what I'm using.

Comment: Is it possible that you created the database using the first model and then changed the model without changing the database somehow and the column in the database is still called 'street' while the column for the complex type is (by convention) named 'address_street'?

Comment: No. The database is mySQL and I manually added the columns (street,city,province,country,postal) to the User table via mySQL workbench. The original table doesn't have the address attributes and I just added it to test out ComplexType. The database was created using the mySQL Workbench and not via VS2012.

Comment: by default EF expects columns in form {complextypename_propertyname} - can you try renaming the columns accordingly (i.e. street to address_street) and try if it works. Alternatively you should be able to add an attribute to the properties to set the column name (e.g. Column("street") for the street property).

Comment: @Pawel: Why not to post your last comment as an answer? I believe that exactly describes both solutions - naming correctly columns to fit default EF conventions or mapping properties to real column names in database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default EF expects columns for properties of complex types in form {complextypename_propertyname}. If you created your tables manually and named columns differently there will be a mismatch. Can you try renaming the columns accordingly (i.e. street to address_street) and try if it works. Alternatively you should be able to add an attribute to the properties on the complex type to tell EF that is should not use the convention but the name you specified (e.g. [Column("street")] for the street property).

Comment: I tested by adding the [Column(...)] annotation to the Address ComplexType and it works. Is the default EF expectation new to EF5? The example I followed didn't mention this.

Comment: The walkthrough you were following applied to EF 4.1 CTP5. AFAIK the convention to prepend columns for complex type properties with complex type name was introduced after this CTP.