# Entity Framework: Unknown column in 'where clause

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am developing an application that will give an overview of what movies are being shown on theaters for the current day.

I get the following exception

> Unknown column 'Extent2.Movie_ID' in 'where clause

This is where the exception is thrown (the extra variable, `movies2`, is just something I did for debugging):

```
public ActionResult MoviesToday()
{                
    var todaysDate = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now).Date;
    var showsToday = db.Shows.Where(s => s.StartTime.Year == todaysDate.Year && s.StartTime.Month == todaysDate.Month && s.StartTime.Day == todaysDate.Day);
    var movies = from firstItem in db.Movies
                 join secondItem in showsToday
                      on firstItem equals db.Movies.Where(x => x == secondItem.Movie).FirstOrDefault()
                 select firstItem;            
    movies = movies.Distinct();

    movies = movies.OrderBy(m => m.Name);
    var movies2 = movies.ToList(); // HERE THE EXCEPTION is THROWN
    return View(movies2);
}
```

This is my `Show` model class:

```
public class Show
{
        public int ID { get; set; }        
        public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
        public string BookingLink { get; set; }
        public string StartTimeAsString { get; set; }

        public Movie Movie { get; set; }
        public Theater Theater { get; set; }
    }
```

Can you see whats wrong?

Edit: Full exception details + stacktrace:

```
System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146232004
  Message=An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.
  Source=EntityFramework
  StackTrace:
       vid System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
       vid System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute[TResultType](ObjectContext context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues)
       vid System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__6()
       vid System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
       vid System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__5()
       vid System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
       vid System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
       vid System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0()
       vid System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
       vid System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
       vid System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
       vid CinemaWeb.Controllers.MoviesController.MoviesToday() i d:\Development\Cinema\CinemaWeb\Controllers\MoviesController.cs:rad 31
       vid lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
       vid System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
       vid System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       vid System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       vid System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.ActionInvocation.InvokeSynchronousActionMethod()
       vid System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
       vid System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       vid System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
       vid System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult](IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
       vid System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       vid System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d()
       vid System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
  InnerException: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException
       HResult=-2147467259
       Message=Unknown column 'Extent2.Movie_ID' in 'where clause'
       Source=MySql.Data
       ErrorCode=-2147467259
       Number=1054
       StackTrace:
            vid MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()
            vid MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32& affectedRow, Int64& insertedId)
            vid MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.GetResult(Int32 statementId, Int32& affectedRows, Int64& insertedId)
            vid MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean force)
            vid MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()
            vid MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
            vid MySql.Data.Entity.EFMySqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
            vid System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
            vid System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<Reader>b__c(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c)
            vid System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
            vid System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
            vid System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
            vid System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
            vid System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
       InnerException:
```

Edit 3: I think it is something wrong with the way I set up the mapping between Show and Movie obviously, but examples I find suggests me to implement it this way. For clarity, I want a Show to have one Movie and one Theater..

Comment: *Does* `Movie_ID` exist on the `Shows` table?

Comment: Hmm, yes, but is that not how it is supposed to be? I mean, as you see above my Show has a Movie, which should create a foreign key for a movie in the table, right?

Comment: It depends which one is configured as the principal, but I don't think it's directly related to the exception being thrown. Can you include the full exception details (preferably with stack-trace)?

Comment: @haim770 , I added it. Thanks for taking your time

Comment: Did you make sure the schema of you DB didn't change

Comment: I used to have a property on Show called MovieID and TheaterID, but I figured I should just give it a Movie and Theater instead. My initializer inherits "DropCreateAlways", so that means that the database is recreated everytime, right?

Comment: Keep in mind that mysql does not work well with the mvc framework. I would highly suggest moving to MSSQL as soon as possible or else you will constantly find little thorns like this at a constant rate as you scale your application.

Comment: Ok, I did not know that. Thanks for the advice

Comment: @TravisJ That's a completely and utterly false statement I'm afraid. MVC will work perfectly fine with MySQL.

Comment: @DavidG - Well, I wouldn't call it perfect. Or really even anywhere close to that. Both storage engines are terrible. MyISAM doesn't even support transactions. The row and table locks are inconsistent with design patterns used in a majority of major ORMs. The *connector that produces mysql from c# code is terribly flawed in too many ways*. They take about a year to get through a bug report there, and there are many. Finding out in your live product that there is a bug in a major framework and it will take a year to solve is unacceptable. So you are probably mislead, and at worst misleading.

Comment: @TravisJ There's a huge difference in saying MVC is not compatible with MySQL and saying MySQL has issues with ORMs. An ORM is not MVC. I also assume you are focussing on entity Framework which I have not tried to connect to anything other than MSSQL, but I have used other ORMs that are not only very capable but some even designed specifically for MySQL. That's why your statement is wrong.

Comment: @DavidG - Keep in mind that saying MVC is not compatible is what you simply infer. I said "does not work well" and it does not. It isn't simply Entity Framework it is the SQL PROVIDER that is the problem and this is something which is widely used in applications. Perhaps you can manually compose the mysql and you will have some luck. But that isn't exactly working well. You took your own words and responded to them, but that isn't what I said. My statement is correct, you just apparently cannot read and take things out of context.

Comment: @TravisJ OK, you seem to have descended into insults so this conversation is over. We can agree to disagree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your join is "weird". How is `equals` evaluating `someMovie == anotherMovie` ??

why don't you just:

```
var movies = (from
    s in db.Shows
where
    s.StartTime.Year == todaysDate.Year && 
    s.StartTime.Month == todaysDate.Month && 
    s.StartTime.Day == todaysDate.Day
select
    s.Movie).Distinct().ToList();

var shows = (from
    s in db.Shows
where
    s.StartTime.Year == todaysDate.Year && 
    s.StartTime.Month == todaysDate.Month && 
    s.StartTime.Day == todaysDate.Day
select
    s).ToList();
```

or

```
var shows = (from
    s in db.Shows.Include(x => x.Movies)
where
    s.StartTime.Year == todaysDate.Year && 
    s.StartTime.Month == todaysDate.Month && 
    s.StartTime.Day == todaysDate.Day
select
    s).ToList();

var movies = shows.Select(x => x.Movie).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: What I want to do is:
1. Get all shows that is displayed today.
2. With them, I can take out all distinct movies that are displayed today.

Comment: Forget what i mumbled about earlier. You were right. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I made a search, and found this: [Entity Framework 5 complex type and unknown column in field list error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592833/entity-framework-5-complex-type-and-unknown-column-in-field-list-error)

copy:
**By default EF expects columns for properties of complex types in form {complextypename_propertyname}. If you created your tables manually and named columns differently there will be a mismatch. Can you try renaming the columns accordingly (i.e. street to address_street) and try if it works. Alternatively you should be able to add an attribute to the properties on the complex type to tell EF that is should not use the convention but the name you specified (e.g. [Column("street")] for the street property).**

Additionally I advise you to use a property like "Id" in the where clause, I had much issues comparing 2 objects like you did.

Ex:
var movies = from firstItem in db.Movies
                         join secondItem in showsToday
                         on firstItem equals db.Movies.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == secondItem.Movie.ID)
                         select firstItem;

Comment: Using MariaDB and this caught me. I had to specify via attribute explicit column name.