# (Why) is it bad to combine ASP.NET MVC and MySQL?

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc

I am developing an app with ASP.NET MVC and MySQL.

Someone with high ranking told me to "remember that MVC and MySQL don't work well together", and advised me to change to SQL Server.

Before taking his advice I would like to know if anyone else have experience working with these?

Comment: preposterous. https://blogs.oracle.com/MySqlOnWindows/entry/howto_using_mysql_for_visual and http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/822392/Connecting-to-MySQL-from-ASP-NET-MVC-using-Visual and http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/aspnet-identity-using-mysql-storage-with-an-entityframework-mysql-provider

Comment: show me that comment please? generally it is wrong there is no problem with .net, mvc and mysql. But probably there was another context.

Comment: I can't link through my phone, but go to my user, the question I asked yesterday about unknown column... The comment is done to my question

Comment: Hmm yes, that's a very odd (and incorrect) comment made yesterday. For reference... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33374564/entity-framework-unknown-column-in-where-clause#comment54547876_33374564

Comment: Ok, thanks for info!

Comment: So there is no good reason to say that MySQL will work worse then MSSQL. It is just about habbits. like there are less projects when people use linux+php+MSSQL and opposite windows+MySQL versus LAMP and .net+MSSQL. but technically there is no restrictions in our days